# @EJB annotation crashes a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, ejb

I have @EJB annotation such as this in my serlvet

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import stateless.Staff;
public class DisplayStaff extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EJB
        private StaffBean Staff_bean;
        ....
}
```

Without that annotation and its declaration the servlet works and is called . With the annotation I get the error

```
root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class controllers.DisplayStaff

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=controllers.DisplayStaff/Stud_bean,Remote 3.x interface =stateless.StaffBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=stateless.StaffBean,refType=Session into class controllers.DisplayStaff: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/controllers.DisplayStaff/Stud_bean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/controllers.DisplayStaff/Stud_bean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=controllers.DisplayStaff/Stud_bean,Remote 3.x interface =stateless.StaffBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=stateless.StaffBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean not found]]]

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=controllers.DisplayStaff/Stud_bean,Remote 3.x interface =stateless.StaffBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=stateless.StaffBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean not found]]

root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean not found]

root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: stateless.StaffBean#stateless.StaffBean not found

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 logs.
```

Answer (score 1):

The container cannot find your bean in the [JNDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface).

You should usually inject a reference to the remote or local interface of the bean, not the bean itself:

```
@EJB
private StaffBeanRemote Staff_bean;
```

But to be sure, use a JNDI explorer (usually on the admin console of your application server) to see what is the exact JNDI name. Also make sure that the bean itself is deployed and running ok (can be checked also on the admin console)

Answer (score -1):

Declare your referenced bean as static.

```
@EJB
private static StaffBean Staff_bean;
```

Hope this works.
Thank you